# WebStorm clear the read only flag for css files, on a scss file watcher (using node-sass) on TFS

Tags: css, tfs, sass, webstorm, node-sass

We are using TFS for source control, and we just started to use scss. I've added in webstorm the file watcher for scss. But the problem is after we commit our changes, all the files are receiving "Read-only" status.

In Visual Studio or in WebStorm if you modify the file it automatically removes the read only status and checks out that file. How can I do it so when I save an scss files to remove the css status and check out that file automatic so I wouldn't be forced to do it manually every time.

In Visual Studio it does automatically with the plugin Web Compiler and I want to do it also in WebStorm, because is much more easy to work in WebStorm than in Visual Studio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answered you gaved me **Cece** is for clear the RO status for the file I'm editing, in this case the scss file. My request was to remove the RO status for the file that is compiled by the node-sass in this case the css file.

I've created a batch file for the moment with this script:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\TF.exe" checkout %2
node-sass --output-style=compact --source-map-embed=true %1 %2
```

and the Webstorm program is linked with this batch file instead of node-sass and is working perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Check [Changing Read-Only Status of Files](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/2016.1/changing-read-only-status-of-files.html) in WebStorm:

1. To enable explicit removal of read-only status:

In the [Confirmation page](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/2016.1/confirmation.html) of the [Version Control settings](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/2016.1/version-control.html), check the option **Show "Clear Read-Only Status" Dialog**.

2. Changing writable status by icon:

You can make a file writable using the lock icon in the Status bar. Open the desired file in the editor, and click the lock, as shown below:

[image]